# Error on RemixIDE: "ParserError: Expected pragma. import directive, or contract/library/interface definition" at the last line

Tags: error, parser

I am running my code at RemixIDE and facing the error *Remix: ParserError: Expected pragma. import directive, or contract/library/interface definition* in the last line of the code (line 157). Does anyone have any suggestion on why this is happening in my case? I would be most appreciated.

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.0 <8.4;



contract cadeia {

    
    
    event EmissaoPedidoFornecedor1 (address Fornecedor1, int8 DefBasicas1, int8 DefBasicas2, int8 DefBasicas3);
    event DespachoPedidoFornecedor1 (int8 NSU1, int8 Quantidade1, int8 Lote1, int8 NSU2, int8 Quantidade2, int8 Lote2, int8 NSU3, int8 Quantidade3, int8 Lote3);
    event EmitirNotaFornecedor1 (address Operador1, int8 NSU1, int Quantidade1, int8 Preco1, int8 NSU2, int Quantidade2, int8 Preco2, int8 NSU3, int Quantidade3, int8 Preco3);
    
    event EmissaoPedidoFornecedor2 (address Fornecedor2, int8 DefBasicasA, int8 DefBasicasB, int8 DefBasicasC);
    event DespachoPedidoFornecedor2 (int8 NSUA, int8 QuantidadeA, int8 LoteA, int8 NSUB, int8 QuantidadeB, int8 LoteB, int8 NSUC, int8 QuantidadeC, int8 LoteC);
    event EmitirNotaFornecedor2 (address OperadorA, int8 NSUA, int QuantidadeA, int8 PrecoA,int8 NSUB, int QuantidadeB, int8 PrecoB, int8 NSUC, int QuantidadeC, int8 PrecoC);
    
    event ReceberProdutoProdutor(string hash);
    event ReceberNotaProdutor (address Fornecedor1, address Fornecedor2, int8 DefBasicas1, int8 DefBasicas2, int8 DefBasicas3, int8 DefBasicasA, int8 DefBasicasB, int8 DefBasicasC);
    event FabricarProdutor (address Operador1, address Operador2, int8 PreProdutosku1, int8 PreProdutosku2, int8 PreProdutosku3, int8 PreProdutoskuA, int8 PreProdutoskuB, int8 PreProdutoskuC); 
    event ProducaoProduto1Produtor (string Produto1, address Distribuidor, int8 S, int8 Quantidade12B, int8 Unidade12B, int8 Preco12B);
    event ProducaoProduto2Produtor (string Produto2, int8 R, int8 Quantidade3AC, int8 Unidade3AC, int8 Preco3AC);
    event DespachoPedidoProdutor1 (string Produto1, address Distribuidor, int8 S, int Quantidade12B, int8 Unidade12B, int8 Preco12B);
    event DespachoPedidoProdutor2 (string Produto2, address Distribuidor, int8 R, int Quantidade3AC, int8 Unidade3AC, int8 Preco3AC);
    event EmitirNotaProdutor1 (string Produto1, address Distribuidor, int8 S, int Quantidade12B, int8 Unidade12B, int8 Preco12B );
    event EmitirNotaProdutor2 (string Produto2, address Distribuidor, int8 R, int Quantidade3AC, int8 Unidade3AC, int8 Preco3AC);
    
    
    event ReceberProdutoDistribuidor (string hash);
    event ReceberNotaDistribuidor (address Operador1, address Operador2, address Fornecedor1, address Fornecedor2, int8 DefBasicas1, int8 DefBasicas2, int8 DefBasicas3, int8 DefBasicasA, int8 DefBasicasB, int8 DefBasicasC);
    event DespachoPedidoDistribuidor (int8 DefBasicas1, int8 DefBasicas2, int8 DefBasicas3, int8 DefBasicasA, int8 DefBasicasB, int8 DefBasicasC); 
    event EmitirNotaDistribuidor (address Distribuidor, int8 DefBasicas1, int8 DefBasicas2, int8 DefBasicas3, int8 DefBasicasA, int8 DefBasicasB, int8 DefBasicasC);
    
    
    event ReceberProdutoCliente1 (string hash);
    event ReceberNotaCliente1 (int8 DefBasicas1, int8 DefBasicas2, int8 DefBasicas3);
    
    
    
    struct DefBasicas1 {int8 NSU1; int8 Quantidade1; int8 Preco1; int8 Peso1;}        }
    struct DefBasicas2 {int8 NSU2; int8 Quantidade2; int8 Preco2; int8 Peso2;}
    struct DefBasicas3 {int8 NSU3; int8 Quantidade3; int8 Preco3; int8 Peso3;}
    struct DefBasicasA {int8 NSUA; int8 QuantidadeA; int8 PrecoA; int8 PesoA;}
    struct DefBasicasB {int8 NSUB; int8 QuantidadeB; int8 PrecoB; int8 PesoB;}
    struct DefBasicasC {int8 NSUC; int8 QuantidadeC; int8 PrecoC; int8 PesoC;}
        
    function PedidoFornecedor1 (address Fornecedor1, int8 DefBasicas1, int8 DefBasicas2, int8 DefBasicas3) public {
        emit EmissaoPedidoFornecedor1 (Fornecedor1, DefBasicas1, DefBasicas2, DefBasicas3);}
            
    function PedidoFornecedor2 (address Fornecedor2,  int8 DefBasicasA, int8 DefBasicasB, int8 DefBasicasC) public {
        emit EmissaoPedidoFornecedor2 (Fornecedor2, DefBasicasA, DefBasicasB, DefBasicasC);}
            
    function DespachoFornecedor1 (int8 NSU1, int8 Quantidade1, int8 Lote1, int8 NSU2, int8 Quantidade2, int8 Lote2, int8 NSU3, int8 Quantidade3, int8 Lote3) public {
        emit DespachoPedidoFornecedor1 (NSU1, Quantidade1, Lote1, NSU2, Quantidade2, Lote2, NSU3, Quantidade3, Lote3);}
            
    function DespachoFornecedor2 (int8 NSUA, int8 QuantidadeA, int8 LoteA, int8 NSUB, int8 QuantidadeB, int8 LoteB, int8 NSUC, int8 QuantidadeC, int8 LoteC) public {
        emit DespachoPedidoFornecedor2 (NSUA, QuantidadeA, LoteA, NSUB, QuantidadeB, LoteB, NSUC, QuantidadeC, LoteC);}
            
    function NotaFornecedor1 (address Operador1,int8 NSU1, int Quantidade1, int8 Preco1, int8 NSU2, int Quantidade2, int8 Preco2, int8 NSU3, int Quantidade3, int8 Preco3) public {
        emit EmitirNotaFornecedor1 (Operador1, NSU1, Quantidade1, Preco1, NSU2, Quantidade2, Preco2, NSU3, Quantidade3, Preco3);}
            
    function NotaFornecedor2 (address Operador2, int8 NSUA, int QuantidadeA, int8 PrecoA,int8 NSUB, int QuantidadeB, int8 PrecoB, int8 NSUC, int QuantidadeC, int8 PrecoC) public {
        emit EmitirNotaFornecedor2 (Operador2, NSUA, QuantidadeA, PrecoA, NSUB, QuantidadeB, PrecoB, NSUC, QuantidadeC, PrecoC);}
            
            
            
    function ReceberProdutoProd (string memory hash, int8 NSU1, int8 NSU1_recebido, int8 NSU2, int8 NSU2_recebido, int8 NSU3, int8 NSU3_recebido, int8 NSUA, int8 NSUA_recebido,  int8 NSUB, int8 NSUB_recebido, int8 NSUC, int8 NSUC_recebido) public {
        emit ReceberProdutoProdutor (hash);
            assert (NSU1_recebido==NSU1);
            assert (NSU2_recebido==NSU2);
            assert (NSU3_recebido==NSU3);
            assert (NSUA_recebido==NSUA);
            assert (NSUB_recebido==NSUB);
            assert (NSUC_recebido==NSUC);}

            
            
    function ReceberNotaProd (address Fornecedor1, address Fornecedor2, int8 DefBasicas1, int8 DefBasicas2, int8 DefBasicas3, int8 DefBasicasA, int8 DefBasicasB, int8 DefBasicasC) public {
        emit ReceberNotaProdutor (Fornecedor1, Fornecedor2, DefBasicas1, DefBasicas2, DefBasicas3, DefBasicasA, DefBasicasB, DefBasicasC);}
        
    struct PreProdutosku1 {int8 NSU1; int8 Quantidade1; int8 Lote1; int8 Turno1;}
    struct PreProdutosku2 {int8 NSU2; int8 Quantidade2; int8 Lote2; int8 Turno2;}
    struct PreProdutosku3 {int8 NSU3; int8 Quantidade3; int8 Lote3; int8 Turno3;}
    struct PreProdutoskuA {int8 NSUA; int8 QuantidadeA; int8 LoteA; int8 TurnoA;}
    struct PreProdutoskuB {int8 NSUB; int8 QuantidadeB; int8 LoteB; int8 TurnoB;}
    struct PreProdutoskuC {int8 NSUC; int8 QuantidadeC; int8 LoteC; int8 TurnoC;}
        
            
    function FabricarProd (address Operador1, address Operador2, int8 PreProdutosku1, int8 PreProdutosku2, int8 PreProdutosku3, int8 PreProdutoskuA, int8 PreProdutoskuB, int8 PreProdutoskuC) public {
        emit FabricarProdutor (Operador1, Operador2, PreProdutosku1, PreProdutosku2, PreProdutosku3, PreProdutoskuA, PreProdutoskuB, PreProdutoskuC);}
        
    struct S { uint8 NSU1; uint8 NSU2; uint8 NSUB;}
        int x;
            mapping(uint8 => mapping(uint8 => S)) data1;
                
           
    function ProducaoProduto1Prod (string memory Produto1, address Distribuidor, int8 S, int8 Quantidade12B, int8 Unidade12B, int8 Preco12B) public {
        emit ProducaoProduto1Produtor (Produto1, Distribuidor, S, Quantidade12B, Unidade12B, Preco12B);}
            
            
    struct R { uint8 NSU3; uint8 NSUA; uint8 NSUC;}
        int y;
            mapping(uint8 => mapping(uint8 => R)) data2;
        
    function ProducaoProduto2Prod (string memory Produto2, int8 R, int8 Quantidade3AC, int8 Unidade3AC, int8 Preco3AC) public {
        emit ProducaoProduto2Produtor (Produto2, R, Quantidade3AC, Unidade3AC, Preco3AC);}
        
    function DespachoPedidoProd1 (string memory Produto1, address Distribuidor, int8 S, int8 Quantidade12B, int8 Unidade12B, int8 Preco12B) public {
        emit DespachoPedidoProdutor1 (Produto1, Distribuidor, S, Quantidade12B, Unidade12B, Preco12B);}
            
    function DespachoPedidoProd2 (string memory Produto2, address Distribuidor, int8 R, int8 Quantidade3AC, int8 Unidade3AC, int8 Preco3AC) public {
        emit DespachoPedidoProdutor1 (Produto2, Distribuidor, R, Quantidade3AC, Unidade3AC, Preco3AC);}    
            
    function EmitirNotaProd1 (string memory Produto1, address Distribuidor, int8 S, int Quantidade12B, int8 Unidade12B, int8 Preco12B) public {
        emit EmitirNotaProdutor1 (Produto1, Distribuidor, S, Quantidade12B, Unidade12B, Preco12B);}
            
    function EmitirNotaProd2 (string memory Produto2, address Distribuidor, int8 R, int Quantidade3AC, int8 Unidade3AC, int8 Preco3AC) public {
        emit EmitirNotaProdutor2 (Produto2, Distribuidor, R, Quantidade3AC, Unidade3AC, Preco3AC);}
            
        
    function ReceberProdutoDist (string memory hash, int8 NSU1, int8 NSU1_recebido, int8 NSU2, int8 NSU2_recebido, int8 NSU3, int8 NSU3_recebido, int8 NSUA, int8 NSUA_recebido, int8 NSUB, int8 NSUB_recebido,int8 NSUC, int8 NSUC_recebido ) public {
        emit ReceberProdutoDistribuidor (hash);
        assert (NSU1_recebido==NSU1);
        assert (NSU2_recebido==NSU2);
        assert (NSU3_recebido==NSU3);
        assert (NSUA_recebido==NSUA);
        assert (NSUB_recebido==NSUB);
        assert (NSUC_recebido==NSUC);}


        
    function ReceberNotaDist (address Operador1, address Operador2, address Fornecedor1, address Fornecedor2,  int8 DefBasicas1, int8 DefBasicas2, int8 DefBasicas3, int8 DefBasicasA, int8 DefBasicasB, int8 DefBasicasC) public {
        emit ReceberNotaDistribuidor (Operador1, Operador2, Fornecedor1, Fornecedor2, DefBasicas1, DefBasicas2, DefBasicas3, DefBasicasA, DefBasicasB, DefBasicasC);}
        
    
            
    function DespachoPedidoDist (int8 DefBasicas1, int8 DefBasicas2, int8 DefBasicas3, int8 DefBasicasA, int8 DefBasicasB, int8 DefBasicasC) public {
        emit DespachoPedidoDistribuidor (DefBasicas1, DefBasicas2, DefBasicas3, DefBasicasA, DefBasicasB, DefBasicasC);}
            
    function EmitirNotaDist (address Distribuidor, int8 DefBasicas1, int8 DefBasicas2, int8 DefBasicas3, int8 DefBasicasA, int8 DefBasicasB, int8 DefBasicasC) public {
        emit EmitirNotaDistribuidor (Distribuidor, DefBasicas1, DefBasicas2, DefBasicas3, DefBasicasA, DefBasicasB, DefBasicasC);}
            
            
    function ReceberProdutoClien1 (string memory hash, int8 NSU1, int8 NSU1_recebido,   int8 NSU2, int8 NSU2_recebido,  int8 NSU3, int8 NSU3_recebido, int8 NSUA, int8 NSUA_recebido, int8 NSUB, int8 NSUB_recebido, int8 NSUC, int8 NSUC_recebido) public {
        emit ReceberProdutoCliente1 (hash);
        assert (NSU1_recebido==NSU1);
        assert (NSU2_recebido==NSU2);
        assert (NSU3_recebido==NSU3);
        assert (NSUA_recebido==NSUA);
        assert (NSUB_recebido==NSUB);
        assert (NSUC_recebido==NSUC);}
        
    function ReceberNotaClien1 (int8 DefBasicas1, int8 DefBasicas2, int8 DefBasicas3) public {
        emit ReceberNotaCliente1 ( DefBasicas1, DefBasicas2, DefBasicas3);}
       
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the extra `}` from line 39   `struct DefBasicas1 {int8 NSU1; int8 Quantidade1; int8 Preco1; int8 Peso1;}        }`